# PHP MongoDb, find all referenced documents when collection is indexed array

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following structure in mongo

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5188deba4c2c989909000000"),
        "_type": {
            "0": "Model_Discs"
        }
    },
    "title": "really cool cd",
    "referencedBy": {
         "0": {
           "$ref": "discs",
           "$id": ObjectId("4e171cade3a9f23359e98552") 
        },
         "1": {
           "$ref": "discs",
           "$id": ObjectId("5045c3222b0a82ec46000000") 
        } 
    }
}
```

This is actually an indexed array that holds references to other documents. I to find all the documents that have a reference to ObjectId("5045c3222b0a82ec46000000").
At first I wrote "referencedBy.1.$id": ObjectId("5045c3222b0a82ec46000000") which doesn't work (as expected) because the ObjectId can be found under different index in other documents
i.e.

```
referencedBy.1.$id
referencedBy.5.$id
referencedBy.3.$id
```

So I need to find all documents that reference my ObjectId who are anywhere under the referencedBy DocumentSet. Something like

```
"referencedBy.*.$id": ObjectId("5045c3222b0a82ec46000000")
```

Comment: Can you do a find on the MongoDB shell? And then update your example with the whole JSON document?

Comment: updated to point out that the links are references to the same type of document (though don't think it actually matters)

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite see why you have such a complicated structure. Particularily the "0" and "1" keys are problematic, especially dealing with PHP as it doesn't really like arrays with numerical string keys. The $ref/$id fields come from MongoDBRef, which should avoid as they don't provide you with any functionality.

You should just have:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5188deba4c2c989909000000"),
    "_type": "Model_Discs",
    "title": "really cool cd",
    "referencedBy": [
        ObjectId("4e171cade3a9f23359e98552"),
        ObjectId("5045c3222b0a82ec46000000") 
    ]
}
```

Then you can simply query with:

```
db.collection.find( { referencedBy: new ObjectId("5045c3222b0a82ec46000000") } );
```

Comment: Well, we're working with Shanty over Zend and when I addDocument having specified in the requirements the relation this is what I actually get. I don't like the 0,1, etc. keys either but I don't see much of a choice there. Will try perhaps a different approach over Shanty maybe I can get it to remove these keys. If you happen to know of any example with Shanty where they do exactly this I would really appreciate a link :)

Comment: Avoid any sort of ODM if you have not used MongoDB directly for atleast a few months. You need to learn how it works, and not hide behind (somtimes bad) ODMs. If Shanty is doing this, it's either crap or you're using it wrong.